# Forgot to renew Fictitious Name application within the county. What is the penalty for late filing?

Tags: united-states, small-business, california

I just found out that, if you are doing business in California and the name of the business does not include your last name, then you have to file Fictitious Name Statement. My friend did this almost 6 years ago and completely forgot to reapply in 2015.

According to [this](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=bpc&group=17001-18000&file=17900-17930) we had to reapply within 40 days after expiration. However, it has been almost a year late and I can't find section that talks about late filing penalties.

**So what are the late filing penalties?**

This is for Santa Clara country, but I have impression that all counties have same filing fees (and hence penalties).

Comment: Call them and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked this myself and there is no monetary penalty for late filing. However, since I am late I have to do all publication over again which costs me extra $50.